# how many ways can a group of 15 people be divided into three groups of 3 and three groups of 2

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**6.** In how many ways can a group of $15$ people be divided into three groups of $3$ and three groups of $2$?

That's all. I need help with this question and would prefer the answer in combination notation e.g. $C_{15}^3 \cdot C_{12}^3$ etc.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. Please also use [Mathjax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) when writing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I shall give the  answer in my way in the notation you want.

You simply go on choosing the groups one by one:

$C(15,3)*C(12,3)*C(9,3)*C(6,2)*C(4,2)*C(2,2)$

Now if the groups are **labelled** eg Lions, Tigers, Panthers, etc. you are done.

But if they are **unlabelled** i.e. you can't distinguish between teams with identical numbers, you will need to divide the above result by $3!3!$

---

**NOTE**

The question really should mention, whether the groups are labelled/distinguishable or not. If they don't, you could mention the assumption you have made, or give answers to both options

Answer (score 1):

Arrange all $15$ people in a line and then do two steps to remove duplicates.

$$\frac{15!}{3!3!3!2!2!2!}\times\frac{1}{3!3!}$$

Reasoning: Permute the $15$ people, with the first three sets of three people being the groups of three and the next three sets of two people being the sets of two; remove the duplicates within each of the six groups (at the person level). Then remove the duplicates for the groups of three and the groups of two (at the groups level).

Can be written as, using the multinomial coefficient, $$\frac{{15 \choose 3,3,3,2,2,2}}{3!3!}$$